# Can a browser plugin/addon access my passwords?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, security, browser-addons

It's increasingly becoming the case that many browser extensions and plugins require access to "all my data" (in both Chrome and Firefox; I will not comment on Internet Explorer).

I'm wondering if it's possible for these plugins and addons to access my banking data (for example) when I visit it, or access data submitted through forms.

What are the security implications of addons?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> This post applies only to Firefox and Chromium/Google Chrome. I cannot comment on Internet Explorer, Opera or mobile browsers.
>   Also, my math further down could be wrong, but the basic idea is correct.

Of course this is possible, though, in the case of Firefox and Chrome/Chromium, unlikely.

## Are my passwords (which are stored in the browser) safe?

This answer is one of my favorites: It depends. Passwords that are saved by the browser need to fulfill one important, and, from a security point of view, nightmarish, condition: They need to be [plaintext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plaintext) or revertible to plaintext.

### Plaintext vs. Encrypted vs. Hashed

Why is that bad? Well, imagine someone breaks into a server and steals the password database. There are two possible outcomes:

1. The passwords are plaintext (or easily reversible), so the cracker now has full access to all accounts.
2. The passwords are [*hashed*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) (or encrypted), a brute-force attack against the hashes would be necessary to get the passwords and access to the accounts. Even now that your username and password are stolen, your account is still safe.

Since the browser needs to be able to send the password to websites, it cannot *hash* passwords, it can only [*encrypt*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption) them (or even store them as plaintext). This is something that one should always keep in mind (the same goes for email clients, chat applications, and so forth).

### Just because it is encrypted, doesn't mean it's safe

Firefox, by default, allows you to save passwords. It also [encrypts them](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/password-manager-remember-delete-change-passwords). The same applies to Chromium (see addendum *"Well, it depends..."*). The problem with this is that the key for decryption is also stored with the passwords. This renders the encryption a minor inconvenience for someone who wants your passwords and does not stop them in any way.

### Then don't store the key with the passwords!

That's right, to make the passwords *safer*, we need to get the key away from the encrypted passwords. This is done in Firefox by setting a *Master Password*, which is then used to encrypt and decrypt all your passwords. By using this technique, you separate [the key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_%28cryptography%29) from the encrypted data, which is always a good idea (after all, you're not keeping your front door key on a hook in front of your door on the outside, right?).

### Passwords are only as safe as you make them

So, why did I say earlier that your passwords are now *safer* and not *safe*? Because now the safety of your passwords depends on the password you've chosen. That is, the password "asdf" should not be considered safe in any way; neither is "12345". Good passwords are *long*, because [brute-forcing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute_force_attack) them takes a considerable amount of time. The password "VioletIsAnotherColor" is technically more secure than "D0!l4riZe" because of its length, despite the fact that the second contains special characters. Let's have a short look at that.

> "VioletIsAnotherColor"
>    Length: 20
>    Possible characters: 52 (26 lowercase + 26 uppercase)
>
> "D0!l4riZe"
>    Length: 9
>    Possible Characters: 77 (26 lower + 26 upper + 10 digits + 15 specials)
>    Specials: !"@$%&/()=?*+#-

So, how many attempts do we need to break those passwords, knowing their character sets and length?

> "VioletIsAnotherColor"
>    52<sup>20</sup> = ~20 decillion (~2 × 10<sup>34</sup>)
>
> "D0!l4riZe"
>    77<sup>9</sup> = ~95 quadrillion (~9 × 10<sup>16</sup>)

As we see, the latter password, despite the broader character set, is easier to brute-force than the long one with its limited set. This is because of the length. (Another upside is that the first one is easier to remember.) [See this IT Security question for details on the matter.](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6095/xkcd-936-short-complex-password-or-long-dictionary-passphrase)

So, if possible, [use a passphrase, not a password](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passphrase).

## Back on topic, how safe are my passwords from a spoofing addon?

They're not. This is because addons have access to the website you just visited. They can extract information from it, including entered passwords. Addons are a security risk like any other installed software. Install only addons that you trust.

### Great! How do I know that?

Install only addons from sources you trust. <strike>For Firefox it's [the AddOns page](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox) and for Chromium it's the [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore), or if you trust the author/distributor. Both guarantee that the AddOns are checked and safe.</strike>

Neither the [the Mozilla AddOns page](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox) nor the [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore) are guaranteeing in any way that the addon is safe. They employ automated reviews processes which might or might catch malicious addons. At the end of the day, there is still a risk left.

Only install addons from sources which *you* trust.

### Wait a moment; did you just mention other installed software?

Of course! Nothing hinders other installed software from grabbing your passwords from the browser, performing man-in-the-middle attacks, or even serving a proxy that spoofs your banking websites. The same goes for Browser Plugins. The rule of thumb is: Do not install software you can't trust.

## Conclusion

What should you take away from this?

- Never install software/plugins/addons you do not trust.
- If you are still in doubt, set a master password.
- If still in doubt, don't trust your browser with passwords, never save them.
- If *still* in doubt, never install any addons/plugins.
- If **still** in doubt, use a [live system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_CD), which cannot be tampered with.

## Addendum: "Well, it depends..."

As I came to learn, my assumptions in this paragraph are not 100% correct, and I'd like to correct that. The following information applies only to storage of the passwords on the disk.

### Google Chrome/Chromium

It actually *does* save your passwords in a secure manner on the disk, depending on the operating system it is running on:

#### Microsoft Windows

The Microsoft Windows API `CryptProtectData`/`CryptUnprotectData` is used to encrypt/decrypt the password. This API works with your OS account password, so it is only as secure as that password is.

#### MacOS

The layer for MacOS generates a random key based on the password of the keychain of the current user and adds that key to the keychain. Again, this only is as secure as the password of the user.

#### Linux

Well...let's not talk about it.

Okay, if you have to know, it does exactly what I assumed: it stores the data with a hardcoded password. Why is this the case? Simply because there is no *common* infrastructure in place to handle encrypted data in a way to the other two systems. No, I did not just say that Linux lacks encryption systems or security; there are plenty of keyring/keychain and password storage solutions available *in the userspace*. As it seems, Chrome developers decided to not use one of those. "Why?" is not a question I can answer.

### Firefox

Always uses a generated key which is stored alongside the passwords. Exception is if you set a master password, then this will *also* be used.

Comment: Talk about elaborate. That's the most well rounded answer I've ever seen! Thanks @Bobby

Comment: Realized that while Chrome allows you to limit access for some plugins by URL, Firefox doesn't have *any* addon sandboxing/permissions.

Comment: @Bobby - About your `VioletIsAnotherColor` vs `D0!l4riZe` for password strength.  The first one technically *is* stronger... *when you're using a brute force attack*.  However, another type of attack is the *dictionary attack*, where the attacker methodically goes through, rather than random letters and numbers, words in the dictionary, and combinations of those words.  `VioletIsAnotherColor` could be cracked within ~ 1.2 billion possibilities.  Just to be technical and all, but it's worth noting.  (+1 anyway, btw) :)

Comment: @cullub How do you arrive at 1 billion possibilities? Even if I assume a "small" dictionary with just 60k entries I arrive at 1.2*10^19, and that does not account for upper/lowercase and possible spelling mistakes.

Comment: Oops, thanks - looks like I misread my numbers.  Still, I end up with ~ 1.2*10^21.  That doesn't take into account capitalization, like you said, but it includes pretty much every word in the English language, including like 50,000 that are obsolete. (~200,000 total)  I guess it's still safer than that random letters/numbers one, unless the attacker was smart, and used just the more common words.  The capitalization one isn't a big thing either, because most passwords like this aren't going to have random capitalization - camelCase, WordCaps, and alllowercase are going to cover most.

Comment: Oh, and when was the last time you saw a spelling mistake in a password? :)  I guess it's possible, but most people aren't going to make a password out of something they can't spell.  Either way, ~ 2 sextillion might be a more reasonable number than assuming brute force.  Although I get that the point of this isn't password security :D.  And brute force is a little simpler.

Comment: @cullub Well, theoretically, you'd still have to go through all three variants which means that the searchspace has been tripled...mixtures not accounting (I bet there is someone out there who uses spaces and proper capitalization). But I get what you mean. Yes, there is a certain possibility that the password is easier to crack than one with random replacements, but most of the time that should not hold true. Especially the longer the password gets.

Comment: Well, yes, especially as the password gets longer (more words).  But any password with four or fewer words would be possible to crack within 4 Sextillion, capitalization variants included.

Comment: @cullub You are right, yes, the more words the better, no argument on that. As a note, at 1 billion combinations a second [it should still be around 30k years](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10^21+%2F+10^9+seconds+in+years).

Comment: Leveraging every word in the English language for calculating possibilities assumes that people are using random-english-word password generators. `VioletIsAnotherColor` utilizes words found in the active vocabulary set used by likely 100% of native English speakers. Even a well-educated individual may hit only 10k words, ref: https://www.quora.com/How-many-words-are-in-the-average-English-speakers-working-vocabulary

Smarter brute-force hackers are going to use "dog" and "cat" before "canine" and "feline".

Comment: @datico I was talking about the whole search space, as I tried to make clear. Maybe I failed at that.

Comment: @Bobby sorry, I was referring to the comment above on dictionary attacks and a dictionary size of 60k words (or whatever). Most people who use word-based passwords may only be pulling from their head with an active vocabulary size of 5-10k words. Or even less...it only takes hundreds of words to be conversationally fluent. I'm tempted to experiment on myself now and see how many "random" words I can come up with. Bet it's not nearly as many as I imagine I know. :)